# Polymorphic Python field lookup vs C++ field lookup

Tags: python, c++, inheritance, polymorphism

I am curious as to the differences between how Python and C++ lookup fields using inherited getters. Consider these two code snippets and their outputs.

```py
class Base: 
    x = 10
    def get_x(self):
        return self.x

class Derived(Base):
    x = 20

print(Base().get_x())
print(Derived().get_x())
```

Outputs

```
10
20
```

On the other hand, consider the following C++ ,

```cpp
class Base{
    public:
    int x = 10 ; 
    
    virtual int get_x(){
     return this->x;    
    }
};

class Derived : public Base{
    public:
    int x = 20;
    
}; 

void main(){

cout << Base().get_x() << endl; 
cout << Derived().get_x() << endl; 

};
```

Outputs

```
10
10
```

Why do the two code snippets have different outputs? What inner workings are going on in these code snippets that causes the difference in output? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have different outputs because C++ and Python are two fundamentally different languages and they work in fundamentally different ways.

The C++ version is not logically equivalent to the Python one. The C++ version has two completely different class members named `x` that belong to two different classes. Declaring a class member with the same name as the name of a member of its superclass simply declares another class member, with no relation to the one with the same name in the superclass. It is true that one is a subclass of the other one, but this makes no difference. The getter only knows about one of them, so setting the other class member, with the same name, has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

In **both** C++ and Python, there are two class members, one in `Base` and one in `Derived`.

The fundamental observable difference is that member access in Python is effectively virtual. `self.x` will find `Derived.x` first, if `self` is of type `Derived`. Member access in C++ is static and resolved based on the static type. `this->x` in a member function of `Base` will always find `Base::x`.